# Why get_profile_connections() is returning an empty array when using likedin-api

Tags: python, api, linkedin-api

so I am working on a school project where i'm supposed to get my LinkedIn connections and do some text mining on them. I ran into an API project provided by [tomquirk (github)](https://github.com/tomquirk/linkedin-api/blob/master/DOCS.md)  and it was running properly but when i moved my project to another computer it stops working and now when I try to use `get_profile_connections()` it always returns me an empty array. I don't know what is the problem and I hope i can get some help here.

this is my code:

```
from linkedin_api import Linkedin
api = Linkedin('linkedintestapi2@gmail.com', '*******')

# GET a profile
profile = api.get_profile('mohamad-arune-a26930176')

# GET a profiles contact info
contact_info = api.get_profile_contact_info('mohamad-arune-a26930176')

# GET all connected profiles (1st, 2nd and 3rd degree) of a given profile
connections = api.get_profile_connections('ACoAACnIxL4B6Ff_-AnBiMDQaXXn2jAvma9NkXI')

print(profile)
print(contact_info)
print(connections)
```

and i get this as a result:

{'lastName': 'arune', 'locationName': 'Evansville, Indiana Area', 'student': False, 'elt': False, 'firstName': 'mohamad', 'entityUrn': 'urn:li:fs_profile:ACoAACnIxL4B6Ff_-AnBiMDQaXXn2jAvma9NkXI', 'location': {'basicLocation': {'countryCode': 'us', 'postalCode': '47521'}, 'preferredGeoPlace': 'urn:li:fs_region:(us,244)'}, 'headline': 'Student at azazzaz', 'profile_id': 'ACoAACnIxL4B6Ff_-AnBiMDQaXXn2jAvma9NkXI', 'experience': [], 'skills': [], 'education': [{'entityUrn': 'urn:li:fs_education:(ACoAACnIxL4B6Ff_-AnBiMDQaXXn2jAvma9NkXI,568801875)', 'timePeriod': {'endDate': {'year': 2009}, 'startDate': {'year': 2002}}, 'degreeName': 'azazazaz', 'schoolName': 'azazzaz', 'fieldOfStudy': 'azazzaz'}]}

{'email_address': 'linkedintestapi2@gmail.com', 'websites': [], 'phone_numbers': []}

[]

Comment: Were you expecting a certain number of connections?  From your question it is not clear if you are concerned about the type of data (array- actually a 'list') or the contents (no data, which is represented by an empty list '[]') being returned.

Comment: @SurestTexas This method is supposed to return all 1st, 2nd and 3rd degree connections of my account, and yes I  am concerned actually about the content,  I don't know why i don't get any result in my list.

Comment: Did you fix the issue?

Comment: @LoBellin I had to uninstall the whole package and install it again, this fixed the problem temporarily.

Comment: @TheGlowdark Yeah I installed it from the GIT repo and it ran smoothly. Thanks anyway for the answer!